# ast.literal_eval() throws an error when passed parameter evaluated to be a normal string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python function to which a string is passed as parameter,
the parameter may be a string representation of **int**, **array**,**dictionary** or a **normal string**

for **int,array and dictionary** its working properly, but if the parameter is a **normal string** the **ast.literal_eval()** throws error

```
import ast

# below statements throw error 
#output_value = ast.literal_eval('someNormalString')  
#output_value = ast.literal_eval('name1 name2 name3')

#below statements work fine
output_value = ast.literal_eval('5')
output_value = ast.literal_eval('[{"id":"XYZ_GTTC_TYR", "name":"Suction"}]')
output_value = ast.literal_eval('["name1","name2"]')
print(output_value)
```

is there any way to to handle it if the param is just a **normal string**?

below is my python function

```
def func(key):
    value = ast.literal_eval(value)
    return value
```

Comment: You should preferably know whether your value is supposed to represent something that can be eval'd or not. What if you have a string that *looks* like a valid literal, but is *supposed* to be a plain string?

Comment: Side note: those are valid list and dictionary literals, but they also happen to be valid JSON. Are you sure JSON isn't what you need to be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to understand what's happening here is to think of `ast.literal_eval` as a (highly simplified) python interpreter, which evaluates what's inside the string.

When you run `ast.literal_eval('someNormalString')`, it's as if you told python to evaluate `someNormalString` - which obviosuly raises an error.

Try: `ast.literal_eval("'someNormalString'")` so `ast` is evaluating `'someNormalString'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The code is viewing the string as `someNormalString` but it actually needs to use `'someNormalString'`. To achieve this, alter the code like so:

```
output_value = ast.literal_eval("'someNormalString'")  
output_value = ast.literal_eval("'name1 name2 name3'")
```